# Indication Colour for New Emails?

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird, colors

I've recently upgraded Mozilla Thunderbird to v3 on Windows XP.

In v2 I think when new (POP3) emails were downloaded, there were a little star icon next to my local folders where it's filtered to indicate new emails. In v3, it seems they've changed it to use different colour to highlight the folder instead. Whereas folders with existing unread emails are highlighted in bold black, folders with new unread emails are highlighted in this light grey greenish colour that's really hard to see.

Does anyone how to modify the colour? 
I'm guessing it's either some lines in a `userChrome.css` file, or modifying a field in the config editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css):

> userChrome.css in the [chrome folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder#Folders) is
>   a CSS file that can be used to change
>   the way Mozilla applications'
>   interfaces look. This file does not
>   exist in a new profile. You can create
>   it manually.

From [Thunderbird 3.0 - New Features and Changes/Themes](http://www.google.fr/url?q=http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.0_-_New_Features_and_Changes/Themes%23Color_for_New_Mail&usg=AFQjCNGzZo4LorHs1Bn86lClqKQxodtuMA&ei=zknpS_inEKaGmwP-z5HkDA&sa=X&oi=section_link&resnum=3&ct=legacy&ved=0CCEQygQ):

> **Color for New Mail**
>
> Previously, new messages in a folder
>   were indicated by an orange star and
>   the folder turning bold. In the
>   default theme, the star has been
>   replaced by the folder name changing
>   color. Unfortunately, this color is
>   picked from the desktop theme, and may
>   result in awkward combinations. To set
>   the color to something more suitable,
>   use the following entry:
>
> Windows and Linux:
>
> `treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(folderNameCol, newMessages-true) {`
>   `color: red !important; }`
>
> This will change the color for all
>   states. You can have different colors,
>   e.g., when the folder is selected
>   (omit the focus part below), and when
>   it has focus:
>
> `treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(folderNameCol, newMessages-true, selected, focus) {`
>   `color: orange !important; }`
>
> Using the two entries above, the
>   new-mail indication results in a red
>   folder name if it isn't focused, and
>   turns orange if it has focus (in which
>   case the background color should be
>   blue with the Windows Classic desktop
>   theme, thus giving a nice contrast).
>   You can specify any color as #rrggbb
>   with 2-digit hexadecimal values 00-FF
>   for red, green, and blue.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://forum.userstyles.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=559) appears to point the way.

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(unread){color:red!important}
```